# Gmail Actions in Inbox: End to end example with google apps account

Tags: google-schemas

Is there a restriction with google apps accounts to test actions in inbox with schema?
I tried the example but no buttons showed in inbox. The app was created with a google apps account in appengine.

The received mail is :

```
Delivered-To: XXX@XXX.XXX
Received: by 10.70.62.71 with SMTP id w7csp85423pdr;
        Fri, 24 May 2013 07:05:48 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.236.167.199 with SMTP id i47mr2955609yhl.91.1369404348508;
        Fri, 24 May 2013 07:05:48 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <3vHOfUQoJBbMfXebTVbhglZfTbe.VhfWTkbhZnsbd.Vhf.Tk@2uix4h7xygsz66weerlq.apphosting.bounces.google.com>
Received: from mail-gh0-f200.google.com (mail-gh0-f200.google.com [209.85.160.200])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id x23si22785441yhx.39.2013.05.24.07.05.48
        for <>
        (version=TLSv1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Fri, 24 May 2013 07:05:48 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of 3vHOfUQoJBbMfXebTVbhglZfTbe.VhfWTkbhZnsbd.Vhf.Tk@2uix4h7xygsz66weerlq.apphosting.bounces.google.com designates 209.85.160.200 as permitted sender) client-ip=209.85.160.200;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of 3vHOfUQoJBbMfXebTVbhglZfTbe.VhfWTkbhZnsbd.Vhf.Tk@2uix4h7xygsz66weerlq.apphosting.bounces.google.com designates 209.85.160.200 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=3vHOfUQoJBbMfXebTVbhglZfTbe.VhfWTkbhZnsbd.Vhf.Tk@2uix4h7xygsz66weerlq.apphosting.bounces.google.com
Received: by mail-gh0-f200.google.com with SMTP id 10so4957746ghy.11
        for <dario@guzik.com.ar>; Fri, 24 May 2013 07:05:48 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=google.com; s=20120113;
        h=mime-version:x-google-appengine-app-id
         :x-google-appengine-app-id-alias:message-id:date:subject:from:to
         :content-type;
        bh=n8aFUSbA2kvCJ/59rvtGWdxlui8OxMGQ5/fz19U42U4=;
        b=LU3rJDyKh6s//uWbPE7zNz/lruJG/vvNpFPQ0E40WudqLbErdX5gvYn2nVl0YYshza
         AtX6ORgZ4sYbG7CGem1DcTX4IlOzBUBJ8e96ep4qeR671eNOUU9nCdlDToZIoQXxu5Ic
         fWQBY6e0o4axoDJQAcb0SmYmRXbT9hyUq+pL3uPX2Girqpy3pQ96mPXm9GRgnnGpagjO
         c1jc1pZbmGJcyxlV79rndskRX8bby5MixeHe61DFlD8UhaVgLf/jjlJ+ifKsIa/TKk4h
         aEqvH4edRoiCbyPUfu2zg1VtGMGbHbSfqJKeHJgYfYty8ZhwrJm21lqzQowuZayt1txc
         PkYQ==
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Received: by 10.58.152.171 with SMTP id uz11mr4806341veb.12.1369404348030;
 Fri, 24 May 2013 07:05:48 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Appengine-App-Id: s~meliacions
X-Google-Appengine-App-Id-Alias: meliacions
Message-ID: <089e0122a452b7eca104dd774b04@google.com>
Date: Fri, 24 May 2013 14:05:48 +0000
Subject: Please review Google Cafe
From: dario@guzik.com.ar
To: dario@guzik.com.ar
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=089e0122a452b7ec9504dd774b01

--089e0122a452b7ec9504dd774b01
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed; delsp=yes

Dear John, please rate Google Cafe between 1 and 5 stars and, optionally,  
add a text comment.

--089e0122a452b7ec9504dd774b01
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Did you enjoy Google Cafe?</title>
   <script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "schema.org",
  "@type": "EmailMessage",
  "description": "Approval request for John's $10.13 expense for office supplies",
  "action": {
    "@type": "ConfirmAction",
    "name": "Approve Expense",
    "handler": {
      "@type": "HttpActionHandler",
      "url": "https://meliacions.appspot.com/approve?expenseId=abc123"
    }
  }
}
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Dear John, please rate Google Cafe between 1 and 5 stars and, optionally, add a text comment.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
--089e0122a452b7ec9504dd774b01--
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google apps accounts seem to not work for the testing purpose. Using the apps script the test did not work for me logged in with my apps account (mail with different domain than gmail.com). The same script worked with a "normal" google account with the domain gmail.com.
Interestingly (automatic) forwarding of the mail from the gmail.com account to the google apps account showed the action button in the google apps account too. So it seems, that in general the feature itself already works in google apps like in normal google accounts, with the exception that the "send mail to yourself for testing"-feature does only work for gmail.com accounts.

Answer (score 2):

As per the warning at the top of the page, the Review Action is currently not supported in Gmail. We expect it to roll out in the next month.