# schema.org ViewAction button not working in Gmail

Tags: google-schemas

I'm trying to create an email with a ViewAction button using schema.org and it isn't working. I'm using the walkthrough on the following page: https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/apps-script-tutorial. Here's the script:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context":       "http://schema.org",
"@type":          "EmailMessage",
"description":    "Check this out",
"action": {
"@type": "ViewAction",
"url":   "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eH8KwfdkSqU"
}
}
</script>
```

I looked up all the elements in the script and it looks to me like they are all being used correctly. So I'm stumped. Anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use a Gmail Account to send the mail from/to or used a google Apps account? In case of the second one, please check my answer here: [Gmail Actions in Inbox: End to end example with google apps account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736999/gmail-actions-in-inbox-end-to-end-example-with-google-apps-account/16748933#16748933)

Comment: what about first case? Since I am sending from abc@gmail.com to abc@gmail.com using SMTP settings still not able to see action button

Comment: yes, the tutorials are failing for me also. I'm sending from myself@gmail, to myself@gmail, posting direct to smtp.gmail.com (authenticated as myself@gmail). According to the tutorials, I should see (yes, validated) actions. But I don't.